# Why mouse-leave trigged when clicked child element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseenter, mouseleave

I created function to show sub list from given list using mouse-enter and mouse-leave, this working good to show sub list, but i need to click (favorite icon) in sub list, when icon is clicked, onmouseleave is triggered, click event on icon is triggered as well, but i need sub list still show up when clicked, here is my code

```
$.fn.hideListGroup = function(id){
    if ($("#sub_list_group_"+id+"").is(':visible')){
        $("#sub_list_group_"+id+"").slideUp('fast');
    }
}

$.fn.showListGroup = function(id, el, thisel) {
    if (!$("#sub_list_group_"+id+"").is(':visible')){
        $("#sub_list_group_"+id+"").slideDown('fast');
    }
};
```

this event was called from ajax result

```
<li onMouseenter="$(this).showListGroup("+id+");" onMouseleave="$(this).hideListGroup("+id+");"></li>
```

and the function when sublist was clicked

```
// clicked sub list
$(document).on("click", ".sidebar-land-groups i", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    /* favorited function */
});
```

how do i make sub list element not slideUp when clicked ? i've added `e.stopPropagation();` but not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can add mouseleave and mouseenter event handlers for icons and use `e.stopPropagation` so that it will not trigger parent's mouse events

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".sidebar-land-groups i", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```